# Need help resolving EOFerror when reading a line

Tags: python, error-handling, eof

My code works for every input that zybooks throws at me, but it spits out an EOFerror on this input:

```
2022-01-01
2022-01-01
2022-01-01
2022-01-01
```

Here is my code so far:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta, time

# 1 Complete read_date()
from datetime import datetime 

def read_date():
    date_string = input()
    return datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%d')
    
"""Read a string representing a date in the format 2121-04-12, create a
date object from the input string, and return the date object"""

# 2. Use read_date() to read four (unique) date objects, putting the date objects in a list
date_list = []
for i in range(4):
    date = read_date()
    while date in date_list:
        date = read_date()
    date_list.append(date)

# 3. Use sorted() to sort the dates, earliest first
sorted_dates = sorted(date_list)

# 4. Output the sorted_dates in order, earliest first, in the format mm/dd/yy
for date in sorted_dates:
    print(date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))

# 5. Output the number of days between the last two dates in the sorted list
#    as a positive number
lastdate = sorted_dates[-1]
secondlastdate = sorted_dates[-2]
daysdifference = (lastdate - secondlastdate).days
print(daysdifference)

# 6. Output the date that is 3 weeks from the most recent date in the list
three_weeks = lastdate + timedelta(weeks = 3)
print(three_weeks.strftime('%B %d, %Y'))

# 7. Output the full name of the day of the week of the earliest day
earliest_day = sorted_dates[0]
print(earliest_day.strftime('%A'))
```

And here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    date = read_date()
  File "main.py", line 7, in read_date
    date_string = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your script requires 4 *different* dates. This code:

```
    while date in date_list:
        date = read_date()
```

asks for a replacement date if the input is a duplicate.

Since you have 4 identical dates, it will stay in this loop, and eventually get an error when it reaches the end of the input without finding a different date.

You can use `try/except` to catch this error and exit the script.

```
try:
    for i in range(4):
        date = read_date()
        while date in date_list:
            date = read_date()
        date_list.append(date)
except EOFError:
    print("Not enough unique dates found, exiting.")
    sys.exit()
```